# Where is the code downloaded by apt source stored?

Tags: apt

I know how to use apt source but where are the files of apt source stored?

Comment: "It will then find and download into the current directory "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are located in same directory as their corresponding `deb` files, use `--print-uris` to get a list of links related to the package source and patch:

```
apt-get source pkg --print-uris
```

And as others mentioned after downloading the source it will be placed in same directory where you ran the command.